# Lets Encrypt para vários domínios com Ubuntu

Tags: php, api, apache, ubuntu, openssl

Eu escrevi um script em PHP que cria novos sites para meus clientes, com domínios diferentes para cada site. Dessa forma, posso criar um novo site customizado para meus clientes de forma rápida. 
Como exemplo, meu dominio está em um site exemplo.com.br e os clientes direcionam seus dominios (por exemplo www.empresa1.com.br, www.empresa2.com.br ) com a configuração de DNS:

Tipo **A** -> 18.228.80.90 (IP ficticio) 
e **CNAME** www.empresa1.com.br -> exemplo.com.br

Dessa forma, quando é digitado o nome do dominio 'empresa1.com.br', automaticamente é direcionado para o servidor 'exemplo.com.br' que verificará o domínio digitado e abrirá o conteúdo do site  correspondente, através de uma simples verificação do nome do dominio pelo PHP.

Como eu poderia implantar o HTTPS do lets Encrypt para vários domínios, sendo que eu só uso um servidor para todos os sites? Eu estou usando atualmente o Certbot, instalado no UBUNTU 18.04, mas das minhas pesquisas e buscas por mais informação, cheguei à conclusão que não será possível utilizá-lo para criar novos certificados, por causa que ele gerencia apenas 1 chave (e cada  chave possui um limite de 100 domínios certificados).

Comment: Sandro, o site é especificamente sobre programação e ferramentas relacionadas (enquanto usadas para programação). Questões de configuração e suporte não estão no escopo. Links para entender melhor o site: [tour], [help] e [A respeito de quais tópicos posso fazer perguntas aqui?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).